# Data Load Wizard - Transformation Rule does not work

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need data in one column are filled automatically with APP_USER when user uploads data with loader wizard.
So I create Transformation rule. I choose column name, then I create 'PLSQL Function body' as Rule type. Function body is:

```
DECLARE
 somevariable varchar2(100);
BEGIN
somevariable := V('APP_USER');
 return somevariable;
END;
```

But is does nothing. All rows are empty in this column. Why?
And one more question; how to make this solumn hidden (user will not see this column in 'target column' combo-box)?
Regards

Comment: To create a "hidden column" just select the columns you want to display, omit the others. So instead of "Select * from table;." to populate the combo_box use "Select col1, col2 ... from table;"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too much code; could be rewritten to a single line:

```
return :APP_USER;
```

Don't know about the *hidden* column.

Comment: I studied that and looks like Transformation Rule works ONLY if mapping is done by user. If no mapping is done by user (table column would not receive any data) then Transformation Rule will not fire.

Comment: Column can be deleted in 'mapping' tab.

Answer (score 0):

I studied that and looks like Transformation Rule works ONLY if mapping is done by user. If no mapping is done by user (table column would not receive any data) then Transformation Rule will not fire.
So this must be done via Trigger.